# Collision objects aren't preventing falling in Unity

Tags: unity, collider

This is a super basic question, but I have absolutelly no clue why there is no collision and the player continues to fall. Im following [FreeCodeCamp](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=gB1F9G0JXOo&t=1415s&ab_channel=freeCodeCamp.org)(minute 37:20). This is what I have:
[image]
What is Happening?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Check the `Layer Collision Matrix` of your Physics 2D project settings to make sure the "Default" layer reacts to itself. I've seen this mysteriously get turned off before.

To access this, Go to **Edit > Project Settings…** then click on the **Physics 2D** label on the left. The Layer Collision Matrix is at the very bottom of the list of settings. This matrix controls whether layers react to other layers, including themselves.

[image: Phyics layer settings]

Comment: Could you provide me a path to follow? Since I'm new, Im stuck a bit

Comment: Edit > Project Settings… . Then Physics2D tab. The layer matrix is way down at the bottom of the window.

Comment: There is a lot of things unmarked, should I mark all of them?

Comment: Sure. Just make sure the check mark that lines up between the "Default" row and the "Default" column is checked.